# Black screen after flashing CAF ROM

Tags: nexus-5

On a Nexus 5 D820 with the latest Google stock images installed. Note: data formatted as ext4.

Steps taken:

1) flashed hammerheadcaf TWRP

2) wiped all data

3) flashed CM13 CAF zip

4) 2 errors, same: unknown command: [log]

Power off, and then attempted a boot. Nothing. Just a black screen. **Do I need an older Nexus 5 Bootloader/Radio Image?**

Edit: This may be screen-related. My N5 has had its screen replaced, and others seem to *possibly* have a similar issue.